# how to change transparency of a color in c#

Tags: c#

I am using SSRS reportviewer to generate a report using objects. In my program, I am asking the user to input a string of commonly known colors such as `"Red"`, "`Blue"`, etc. I would like to then generate three shades of this color and use this color to fill an area chart in my report. I do so my changing the opacity (alpha) of the color.

This is my code that converts the string to color:

```
 newitem.ChartColor = "red";
 Color mycolor = Color.FromName(newitem.ChartColor);
```

However, now I would like to generate two more colors with same shade as red but different alpha (opacity) so that they appear lighter, something like `#56FF0000`

I tried passing a value to the `A` property of Color however, it is read-only.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a method that does exactly what you need [Color.FromArgb(int alpha, Color baseColor)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9.aspx).

Valid `alpha` values are 0 through 255. Where 255 is the most opaque color and 0 a totally transparent color.

Use example

```
Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(newAlpha, mycolor);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set with this function

```
    static Color SetTransparency(int A, Color color)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think 'SetTransparency' is a clear name. It doesn't alter the property of an existing color, but instead creates and returns a new one.

Answer (score 7):

I think what needs to be included among these answers is that the alpha value indicates how transparent the color is with 0 being the most transparent and with 255 being the most opaque. Here is a summary:

```
                     A L P H A    V A L U E
0 [<--- most transparent]  ... ... ... [most opaque --->] 255
```

Comment: Upvoted. I added it to my original answer for better visibility.

Comment: Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I created a handy extension method.

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    ...
    public static Color WithA(this Color color, int newA) => Color.FromArgb(newA,color);
}
```

Usage:

```
newitem.ChartColor = "red";
Color mycolor = Color.FromName(newitem.ChartColor);

Color myColorAlt1 = myColor.WithA(0x56);
Color myColorAlt2 = myColor.WithA(0x28);
```

or, if you needed it right away:

```
Color mycolor = Color.FromName(newitem.ChartColor).WithA(0x56);
```