# 70% Opacity Color to a Button WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make that effect when I hover a button to still be like 30% transparent (so you can see the background image from the form) but still see some color..

I tried this but this just gives me a blank black:

```
private void roundedButton2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            roundedButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            roundedButton2.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black);
        }

        private void roundedButton2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            roundedButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            roundedButton2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
```

[image]
  Here I have the mouse out and mouse on the button so you can see what I have.
EDIT: Solved it.... now the above code does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: can you show us image of the form

Comment: I hope the Button is sitting __directly__ on the form..?

Comment: yeah is sitting directly on the form. @Lekve See the update!

Comment: Then use `     roundedButton2.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black);` in the Mouse_Enter!

Comment: wow nice it was really that easy...

Comment: also... you know how could I make a transparent textbox?

Comment: Not possible. At least not so easy ..TextBox is legacy and won't play along :-(  (But __maybe__ some pinvoke magic can tickle it) - BTW: You don't really need to change the colors in events as tthey already are tied to them..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753043/how-to-change-transparency-of-a-color-in-c-sharp maybe this will help you

Comment: Problem is solved. @DinaBogdan

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. I changed the code as follows:

```
private void roundedButton2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            roundedButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            roundedButton2.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black);
        }

        private void roundedButton2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            roundedButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            roundedButton2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
```

Had to add *FlatAppearance* before the backcolor.

Comment: You don't really need to change the colors in events as tthey already are tied to them..

Comment: can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204056/transparent-textbox-70-black# ?